# How can I distribute my python desktop application?

Tags: python, windows, pyqt4

I created a GUI app using PyQt4, can distribute that code as a installer? how can I do that

On windows, if the user double-click on the installer it should go through the normal installation wizards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pyinstaller](https://mborgerson.com/creating-an-executable-from-a-python-script) or [cx_freeze](https://pythonprogramming.net/converting-python-scripts-exe-executables/) to create executable files of python scripts/applications.

Command of pyinstaller:

```
pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed <python file name>
```

Note:
It will directly launch the application and not go through installation wizard.